# Send null as a value in ngResource AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.1's ngResource and I'm trying to send `null` as a value in the parameters in a PUT request. Unfortunately, when it is set, Angular will ignore it the parameter and not send it.

Here's some example code:

```
var User = $resource('/comments/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
  destroy: { method: 'PUT', params: {content: null} }
});
var user = User.destroy({id:123}, function() {});
```

Angular will instead ignore `content` and not send the key nor the null value.

How can I make Angular send null?

Comment: Why are you trying to send null? All parameter values are sent as strings, so Angular wouldn't be able to send it anyway.

Comment: I was sending null because my API has an upsert endpoint so sending a content:null is supposed to destroy it instead. There were various reasons in terms of trade offs that meant that an upsert provided a cleaner API as opposed to a `DESTROY` request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Lèse has pointed out, the javascript type `null` is not a valid value for a URL parameter.

A javascript `null` value isn't the same as the string `'null'`. So if you wanted your URL to look like `/comments/123?content=null` just provide a string `'null'`. URL parameters are not JSON and a `null` value in javascript doesn't mean the same thing as `content=null` because in the latter case, null would be interpreted by any given server as a string value.

Angular's $http service [filters out null and undefined values in the params object before constructing a url with them](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L985) because there's no standardized way to send `undefined` as a "value" to a server. It just doesn't make sense. However, if you wanted to send a string like `'undefined'` or `'null'` that's fine, but it require implementation on the server side to interpret it as such.

If you're making a `PUT` request, why is some of your data being JSON serialized within the resource and some of it being sent via a URL parameter? Maybe the example code is just poorly represented, but in that example you're sending a `PUT` request with the response body of `{"id": 123}` and the url `/comments/123`. Isn't that redundant? Why aren't you sending the `content` property and data in the JSON string to the server? Then it would actually have the `null` value you're looking for because JSON strings **can** represent a `null` type value. Also, if you're deleting/destroying a record, why aren't you using a `DELETE` request, but instead aliasing a destroy method with a PUT request?

So why not something like this? I'm not sure what the `User` has to do with it...

```
var Comment = $resource('/comments/:id', {id: @id}, {
  destroy: {method: 'PUT'}
});
new Comment({id: 123, content: null}).$destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments that have been made since my question means that `null` shouldn't be sent as it cannot be properly encapsulated in HTTP params. However, it can be encapsulated in JSON. Why would anyone want to send a null value? Because sending null to an `upsert` [1] end point means destroy. Unfortunately, there is no way to define the default of `content` to be null in the `.destroy()` call.

The answer that I settled with was:

```
var Comment = $resource('/comments/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
  destroy: { method: 'PUT' }
});
var comment = Comment.destroy({id:123, content: null});
```

This is exactly like the @jbielick's answer and he does a fine job explaining the reason why it didn't work as a default param but works if it were provided as part of the input object to JSONify.

1. Upsert is a merging of the words insert and update.