# AngularJS - submit empty form fields as null rather than completely omitting it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms

This is my HTML / Angular:

```
<form ng-submit="ctrl.add()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.username"> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" ng-model="ctrl.user.password" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" ng-model="ctrl.user.email" required> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Country</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.userextended_set.country" ng-trim="false"> 
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"> 
</form>
```

The issue is, when a user hits submit without filling out the "Username" or "Country" section, AngularJS sends a JSON object to the backend with just "email"  and "password" as keys in the dictionary. "Username" and "Country" keys do not exist in the dictionary (from now on, refer to the "Country" field as "userextended_set" because that it what the field in my ng-model is called). How do I get AngularJS to not completely omit it, and to at least send the keys with a value of "null"?

Edit: It's weird because even though I have ng-trim="false" on the "userextended_set" field, if I initially submit the form without filling anything in "userextended_set", AngularJS does not send "userextended_set" as a key in the JSON object. But if I type something into "userextended_set" and then delete it, and then hit submit, JSON sends "userextended_set" as a key.

Comment: probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25230155/2495283

Comment: I believe there is no standard way to override this. Are you having problems on your backend because of this? What is your backend stack? I am using Spring MVC and luckily it fills the missing attributes with null automatically. My suggestion is: treat it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to the input field the attribute:

```
ng-trim="false"
```